# SQL Server Averages/Sums/Groups/Counts Query Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, average

I have the following table:

```
╔══════════╦════════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ PlayerID ║ GameID ║ Stat1 ║ Stat2 ║
╠══════════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║        1 ║ A      ║     2 ║     1 ║
║        1 ║ B      ║     4 ║     2 ║
║        1 ║ C      ║     6 ║     5 ║
║        2 ║ A      ║     2 ║     4 ║
║        2 ║ B      ║     2 ║     6 ║
║        2 ║ C      ║     2 ║     8 ║
║        2 ║ D      ║     4 ║     2 ║
║        2 ║ E      ║     6 ║     1 ║
║        3 ║ A      ║     5 ║     9 ║
║        3 ║ G      ║     6 ║     4 ║
║        3 ║ H      ║     4 ║     2 ║
║        3 ║ N      ║     8 ║     6 ║
╚══════════╩════════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

```
╔══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ PlayerID ║ GameCount ║ Stat 1 Avg / Game ║ Stat 2 Avg / Game ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║        1 ║         3 ║ 4                 ║ 2.66              ║
║        2 ║         5 ║ 3.2               ║ 4.2               ║
║        3 ║         4 ║ 5.75              ║ 5.25              ║
╚══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

The game count should be the total number of games played per player and the stats should be the average per game. Basically the calculation for PlayerID 1 is the following:

"Stat1 Avg / Game" = (2 + 4 + 6) / 3
"Stat2 Avg / Game" = (1 + 2 + 5) / 3

I have tried numerous variations of the same query with a combination of SUMS and COUNTS but the GameCount never comes out correct. An example of what I have tried is below

```
SELECT PlayerID, 
COUNT(GameID) AS GameCount, 
SUM(Stat1) / COUNT(GameID)  "Stat 1 Avg / Game",
SUM(Stat2) / COUNT(GameID)  "Stat 2 Avg / Game"
FROM PublishedStats A
GROUP BY PlayerID

SELECT PlayerID, 
COUNT(GameID) OVER (PARTITION BY PlayerID) AS GameCount, 
SUM(Stat1) /  COUNT(GameID) OVER (PARTITION BY PlayerID) "Stat 1 Avg / Game", 
SUM(Stat2) /  COUNT(GameID) OVER (PARTITION BY PlayerID) "Stat 2 Avg / Game", 
FROM Stats
GROUP BY PlayerID, GameID
```

Comment: I think your first query is correct and you don't need the second one.

Comment: Unless `GameID` contains NULL values, I agree with @Jasmine - which values do you actually get from your first query?

Comment: @Jasmine Sorry I created the base data wrong, PlayerID 1 should have two stats for Game A and one for Game B. In the above query it would state that he played 3 games when in fact he played 2 because there are two different stats for the one game – chunt 1 hour ago delete

Comment: @chunt . . . How are the averages calculated if there are multiple rows for one game?

Comment: OK, so a game can generate one to many stats rows? If you normalized this table correctly, your query would be easy. Your current table structure is efficient, but does make some queries like "how many unique games" difficult because you're recording an unknown number of rows for each game. If you had a game_master table with one row per game (and another table for stats), your query would be simple.

Comment: @Jasmine I do have a master game table with a one to many relationship to the stats. The report I was trying to create and many aggregates with calculations using the aggregates including SUM and COUNTS. Using this syntax solved the GameCount issue "COUNT(DISTINCT GameID) AS GameCount"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just add the DISTINCT keyword.

```
SELECT PlayerID, 
COUNT(DISTINCT GameID) AS GameCount, 
AVG(Stat1)  "Stat 1 Avg / Game",
AVG(Stat2)  "Stat 2 Avg / Game"
FROM PublishedStats A
GROUP BY PlayerID
```

Comment: Yes....that's exactly it which is ironic I just tried that before checking...thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SUM(Stat1) / COUNT(DISTINCT GameID)`?

Comment: Yes Markus you are correct, the biggest issue was getting the correct game count